# Dual kinect calibration using powerfull IR LED illuminator

Tags: kinect, camera-calibration

i am using multiple Kinects within the scene. So I need to calibrate them and find the extrinsic parameters like translation and rotation  world coordinate system. Once I have that information, i can reconstruct the scene at highest level of accuracy. the important point is : i want to get submillimeter accuracy and may be it would be nice if i could use powerfull IR projector in my system. But i do not have any Background about  IR sensor and calibration methods. So i need to know about tow subject : 1- is it possible  to add IR LED illuminator to kinect and manage it? 2- if i could add how to calibrate my new system?

Answer (score 0):

Calibration (determining relative transforms (rotation, scale, position)) is only part of the problem. You also need to consider whether each Kinect can handle the interference of the other Kinect's projected IR reference patterns.

"Shake n Sense" (by Microsoft Research) is a novel approach that you may be able to use that has been demonstrated to work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSBDY0RuhS4

Comment: i decide to cover original IR projector of kinect with an rigid object to prevent  interference of the other Kinect's projected IR. The Kinect comes with factory calibration, and the distortion is not visibly evident with the naked eye. However, for the purpose of sensitive application, further calibration is essential in order to enhance the
tracking accuracy.